# Receive empty response from API, and webhook isn't called AWS VPN S2S

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a big trouble right now.

- First, I'm using 2 EC2 instances running Ubuntu 20.04, one for test (staging), and one for release (production). I have them configured similarly.
- I have used AWS S2S to connect with the 3rd partner. We integrate 2 APIs and 1 webhook.

- Once the order is approved, the systems will automatically send request get token and create account to 3rd partner.
- Once the customer paid, the 3rd partner systems will call our webhook with payment results.

- Everything is ok in staging. We can telnet to each other, all apis and webhook work fine.
- But when I sync my code to master branch, put docker to EC2 production for golive.
  I have faced 2 issues:

1. My systems has received empty response from API get token.
   Then I used CURL to test API direcly in EC2 server:

- curl -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -H "Authorization: Basic token" https://url/security/token -> Received token.
- curl -k --location --request POST 'https://url/security/token' 
  --header 'Authorization: Basic token' 
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
  --data-raw '{
  "grant_type": "client_credentials"
  }' -> Received nothing.

Note: The partner checked their network, they showed me the package sended to my systems successfully whenever I run CRUL command.

2. My systems didn't show any logs about webhook, in spite of the partner showed me they sended a request to my server. They received errors code 500 timeout from webhook.

-> I tried to use VPC flow log. It accepted all IN and OUT traffic.

**Can anyone tell me the cause of the error I'm facing or how to check it?**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.